# Polymorphic nhibernate query with projection

Tags: nhibernate

Using a single table for a class hierarchy I would like to use a projection to flatten the hierarchy to present a list of results to the user.

Is there a way to do this using HQL or Criteria API without having to issue multiple separate queries or unions?

---

Classes

```
public class A {
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}

public class B : A {
    public virtual DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
    public virtual OtherEntity Other { get; set; }
}

public class C : A {
    public virtual DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class D : A {
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class OtherEntity {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

SQL Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
    Id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Kind char(1) NOT NULL,
    SomeDate datetime NULL,
    Description NULL
)

CREATE TABLE OtherEntity (
    Id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Output projection:

```
public class ItemReport {
    // From A.Id
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    // From B.SomeDate or C.SomeDate
    public virtual DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }

    // From C.Description or D.Description
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    // From B.OtherEntity.Name
    public virtual string OtherName { get; set; }
}
```